# Subtitle in AppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a SliverAppBar with title and subtitle like this:

```
SliverAppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  forceElevated: true,
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  pinned: true,
                  floating: true,
                  snap: false,
                  title: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Container(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0, bottom: 5.0),
                      child: Text('Contest', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
                    Text(_getFiltersString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey[700]),)
                  ]),
```

It runs but if i scroll i receive this error:

```
I/flutter ( 4765): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4765): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 4765): A RenderFlex overflowed by 30 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 4765):
I/flutter ( 4765): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 4765): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 4765): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 4765): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 4765): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 4765): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 4765): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter ( 4765): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter ( 4765): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 4765): The specific RenderFlex in question is:
I/flutter ( 4765):   RenderFlex#968e7 relayoutBoundary=up14 OVERFLOWING
I/flutter ( 4765):   creator: Column ← Semantics ← DefaultTextStyle ← LayoutId-[<_ToolbarSlot.middle>] ←
I/flutter ( 4765):   CustomMultiChildLayout ← NavigationToolbar ← DefaultTextStyle ← IconTheme ← Builder ←
I/flutter ( 4765):   CustomSingleChildLayout ← ClipRect ← ConstrainedBox ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 4765):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 4765):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=176.0, 0.0<=h<=20.3)
I/flutter ( 4765):   size: Size(70.0, 20.3)
I/flutter ( 4765):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 4765):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 4765):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 4765):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 4765):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 4765): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter ( 4765): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 32 of 722 libraries in 2.887ms.
```

What i have to use instead of Column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means that the widget is bigger than the view. Now what you can do is wrap the `Column` in a [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) to let it scroll:

```
SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(...) )
```

Comment: A scroll, inside an appbar ? bad idea